# Using generative adversial networks to synthesizee mouse movement

Tags: artificial-intelligence, generative-adversarial-network

I'm trying to build a GAN that trains on hundreds of thousands to millions of coordinate sets. The coordinate sets are collected by a JavaScript mousemove event listener, and are appended into an array. The array should be about length 250.

Without any prior knowledge of ML, and a requirement to build this with a GAN (as the discriminator used to analyze the mouse movement is quite strict), what would be the proper approach?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an end-to-end example of an image genenrator using a GAN with Microsoft's CNTK and C# .NET.

That author shows the step by step activities in building a GAN. You can adopt the same approach and tweak the code for your training data set.

**Reference:**

[Farragher, M. (2019), Create Any Image with C# And A Generative Adversarial Network, Medium article.](https://medium.com/machinelearningadvantage/create-any-image-with-c-and-a-generative-adversarial-network-6031a4b90dec)

Comment: Hey, I appreciate the comment. Would there be a way to convert this to coordinates though? Instead of images specifically?

Comment: I also found the GitHub source for the article here: https://github.com/mdfarragher/DLR/tree/master/Misc/GanDemo I suggest you clone the project and play around with it. I believe the input shape is specified in:

// create the generator input variable
var generatorVar = CNTK.Variable.InputVariable(new int[] { latentDimensions }, CNTK.DataType.Float, name: "generator_input");

and the discriminator in

var discriminatorVar = CNTK.Variable.InputVariable(new int[] { imageWidth, imageHeight, channels }, CNTK.DataType.Float, name: "discriminator_input");

Look for these and change them.